# Return value in Javascript but it turns out to be undefined

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm new at Javascripts and i'm trying to use Angular UI route, here is my code

```
myApp.config(['$stateProvider', '$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {     
    $stateProvider  
        .state('home', {
            url: '/test',
            templateUrl: '/custom.html'
        })
        .state('detail', {                
            url: '/{examID}',              
            views: {
            '': {
              templateUrl: '/templates/customize.html',
               controller: ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'utils',

                function ( $scope,$stateParams,utils) {
                  $scope.exam = utils.findById($stateParams.examID);
                  console.log('exam is ' + $scope.exam );
                }
                ]
        }            
            }
        }     )    

    }])
```

and this is the service which has findbyID function

```
angular.module('service', [])
.factory('utils', function ( $http) {
  return {
    findById: function findById(id) {
       $http.get('/api/exams/' + id).success(function(response) {
            return response;
    })}
};});
```

i've already follwed this topic but $scope.exam still undefined

[How to return value from an asynchronous callback function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6847697/how-to-return-value-from-an-asynchronous-callback-function)

PS. i've tried to print out response and it's an object

Thx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a place where a lot of developers new to JavaScript stumble.

What is going on here is that you are assigning the return value of `utils.findById()` to `$scope.exam`. The problem is that `utils.findById()` doesn't actually return anything. (When a function doesn't have an explicit `return` statement in JavaScript, the return value is implicitly `undefined`.)

Here is what your service should look like:

```
angular
  .module('service', [])
  .factory('utils', function ($http) {
    return {
      findById: function (id) {
        return $http.get('/api/exams/' + id);
      }
    };
  });
```

You probably noticed that the call to `.success()` has disappeared too! Don't worry. It just moved.

Instead of calling `.success()` on `$http.get()`, we want to call it on `utils.findById()`. Doing this will give you access to the `response` variable in your controller. Because you will have access to the `response` variable, you will be able to assign `response` to `$scope.exam` like so:

```
.state('detail', {
  url: '/{examID}',
  views: {
    '': {
      templateUrl: '/templates/customize.html',
      controller: ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'utils',
        function ($scope, $stateParams, utils) {
          utils.findById($stateParams.examID)
            .success(function (response) {
              $scope.exam = response;
            });
        }
      ]
    }
  }
});
```

Hopefully that cleared it up. If I haven't been clear on anything, please let me know so I can update this answer.

Comment: Yay! :D Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

You have to wait for the ajax call to finish. Modify the code in your **controller** to:

```
$scope.exam;
utils.findById($stateParams.examID).then(function(data) {
    $scope.exam = data.data;
}
```

Read about the concept of '**Promises**' in AngularJS and JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

Use deferred promise, So that it would return value after response

**Service:**

```
angular.module('service', [])
.factory('utils', function ( $http) {
  return {
    findById: function findById(id) {
       var promise=$http.get('/api/exams/' + id);
   return promise;
};});
```

**Controller:**

```
   myApp.config(['$stateProvider', 
  '$urlRouterProvider',function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {     
            $stateProvider  
                .state('home', {
                    url: '/test',
                    templateUrl: '/custom.html'
                })
                .state('detail', {                
                    url: '/{examID}',              
                    views: {
                    '': {
                      templateUrl: '/templates/customize.html',
                       controller: ['$scope', '$stateParams', 'utils',

                        function ($scope, $stateParams, utils) {
                                                   utils.findById($stateParams.examID).then(function(value) {
                        $scope.exam = value;
                        console.log('exam is ' + $scope.exam );
                         });

                        }
                        ]
                       }           
                    }
                })    
        }])
```